# How to fix Expected Identifiers errors C Language

Tags: c, unix, ansi-c

I'm getting two "expected identifier" errors when I compile my code even-though it is written according to ANSI-C standards.
I compiled using the gcc compiler with the flags -Wall -ansi -pedantic.
I know the compiler is old but my university requires me to use it.

Copy paste of the errors:

```
mycomp.c:202:5: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘return’
     return SUCCESS;
     ^
mycomp.c:203:1: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘}’ token
     }
     ^
makefile:10: recipe for target 'mycomp.o' failed
```

I tried reviewing my code and can't find any syntax issue. I tried following the error guide lines, for an instance, add ‘(’ before ‘return’ or ‘(’ before ‘}’ token, but that doesn't change anything and I still get those errors.

The code is long and messy but I only get an error at the very end or it: The last return and last } digit.

```
int main() {  
    char command[SIZE_OF_LINE];
    int commandIndex; int i;
    int numbers[2]; char var[2];

    /* As requested, initializing all complex values to 0 + 0i */
    read_comp(A, NONE, 0 ,0);
    read_comp(B, NONE, 0 ,0);
    read_comp(C, NONE, 0 ,0);
    read_comp(D, NONE, 0 ,0);
    read_comp(E, NONE, 0 ,0);
    read_comp(F, NONE, 0 ,0);

    commandIndex = 0;

    numbers[0] = commandIndex;
    numbers[1] = commandIndex;
    var[0] = '0';
    var[1] = '0';

    for(i = 0; ; i = 0)
        if(!fgets(command, SIZE_OF_LINE, stdin)) {
            i = undefinedCharSkipper(command, i);
            commandIndex = commandIdentifier(command, i);

            if(cmd[commandIndex].func == NULL) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Command does not exist:%s\n", command);
            }

            if(strcmp(cmd[commandIndex].name, "read_comp") == 0) {
                /* Recieving parameters and setting in place */
                i = undefinedCharSkipper(command, i);
                if(letterReceiver(i) != FAIL) {
                    var[0] = letterReceiver(i);
                }

                i = undefinedCharSkipper(command, i);
                if(numberReceiver(command, i) != FAIL) {
                    numbers[0] = numberReceiver(command, i);
                }

                i = undefinedCharSkipper(command, i);
                if(numberReceiver(command, i) != FAIL) {
                    numbers[1] = numberReceiver(command, i);
                }

                /* Running command */
                read_comp(getComplex(var[0]), NONE, numbers[0], numbers[1]);
                end(command, i);
            }

            if(strcmp(cmd[commandIndex].name, "print_comp") == 0 ) {
                /* Recieving parameters and setting in place */
                i = undefinedCharSkipper(command, i);
                if(letterReceiver(i) != FAIL) {
                    var[0] = letterReceiver(i);
                }

                /* Running command */
                print_comp(getComplex(var[0]), NONE, 0, 0);
                end(command, i);
            }

            if(strcmp(cmd[commandIndex].name, "add_comp") == 0 ) {
                /* Recieving parameters and setting in place */
                i = undefinedCharSkipper(command, i);
                if(letterReceiver(i) != FAIL) {
                    var[0] = letterReceiver(i);
                }

                i = undefinedCharSkipper(command, i);
                if(letterReceiver(i) != FAIL) {
                    var[1] = letterReceiver(i);
                }

                /* Running command */
                add_comp(getComplex(var[0]), getComplex(var[1]), 0, 0);
                end(command, i);
            }

            if(strcmp(cmd[commandIndex].name, "sub_comp") == 0) {
                /* Recieving parameters and setting in place */
                i = undefinedCharSkipper(command, i);
                if(letterReceiver(i) != FAIL) {
                    var[0] = letterReceiver(i);
                }

                i = undefinedCharSkipper(command, i);
                if(letterReceiver(i) != FAIL) {
                    var[1] = letterReceiver(i);
                }

                /* Running command */
                sub_comp(getComplex(var[0]), getComplex(var[1]), 0, 0);
                end(command, i);
            }

            if(strcmp(cmd[commandIndex].name, "mult_comp_real") == 0) {
                /* Recieving parameters and setting in place */
                i = undefinedCharSkipper(command, i);
                if(letterReceiver(i) != FAIL) {
                    var[0] = letterReceiver(i);
                }

                i = undefinedCharSkipper(command, i);
                if(numberReceiver(command, i) != FAIL) {
                    numbers[0] = numberReceiver(command, i);
                }

                /* Running command */
                mult_comp_real(getComplex(var[0]), NONE, numbers[0], 0);
                end(command, i);
            }

            if(strcmp(cmd[commandIndex].name, "mult_comp_img") == 0) {
                /* Recieving parameters and setting in place */
                i = undefinedCharSkipper(command, i);
                if(letterReceiver(i) != FAIL) {
                    var[0] = letterReceiver(i);
                }

                i = undefinedCharSkipper(command, i);
                if(numberReceiver(command, i) != FAIL) {
                    numbers[0] = numberReceiver(command, i);
                }

                /* Running command */
                mult_comp_img(getComplex(var[0]), NONE, 0, numbers[0]);
                end(command, i);
            }

            if(strcmp(cmd[commandIndex].name, "mult_comp_comp") == 0) {
                /* Recieving parameters and setting in place */
                i = undefinedCharSkipper(command, i);
                if(letterReceiver(i) != FAIL) {
                    var[0] = letterReceiver(i);
                }

                i = undefinedCharSkipper(command, i);
                if(letterReceiver(i) != FAIL) {
                    var[1] = letterReceiver(i);
                }

                /* Running command */
                mult_comp_comp(getComplex(var[0]), getComplex(var[1]), 0, 0);
                end(command, i);
            }

            if(strcmp(cmd[commandIndex].name, "abs_comp") == 0) {
                /* Recieving parameters and setting in place */
                i = undefinedCharSkipper(command, i);
                if(letterReceiver(i) != FAIL) {
                    var[0] = letterReceiver(i);
                }

                /* Running command */
                abs_comp(getComplex(var[0]), NONE, 0, 0);
                end(command, i);
            }

            if(strcmp(cmd[commandIndex].name, "stop") == 0) {
                stop(NONE, NONE, 0, 0);
                end(command, i);
            }
        }
        else { /* Failed scanning the user's input */
            printf("\n");
            printf("Scanning had failed");
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

Expected results: compilation without error since those are the only 2 errors I am getting.
Actual results: Getting 2 errors.

Comment: You should avoid claiming your code is correct when the compiler is telling you otherwise.  Occam's Razor applies in these circumstances.

Comment: Suggestion: Once you have matched a string to `cmd[commandIndex].name` all subsequent tests can be omitted.  You can do this by using `else if` rather than `if`.

Comment: Please provide a **minimum** verifyable example. You can do this e. g. be removing one `if` block after another. Showing us tons of unrelated code does not really help anyone. Doying this would probably make the problem obvious.

Comment: @Gerhardh Problem already solved but thanks so much for trying to help me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look carefully and indent your code properly.

In the part

```
    }                     //----------------------- (1)
    return SUCCESS;        // -----------------------(2)
}
```

You have a curly brace mismatch., `(1)` indicates the closing brace for `main()` function, so the part marked as `(2)`;  your `return SUCCESS; }` resides in file scope, which is not allowed.

Correct your indentation and take care of the braces.

Comment: @ShadowOverLoad : You could have missed that because you are using the "line-saver" indentation style where the opening brace in on the same line as the statement preceding the compound statement.  It is (IMO) more obvious to place the opening an closing braces on their own line in the same column as each other and to indent _after_ the opening `{`.  Then the braces stand out and can be easily visually matched.  Here you have omitted the opening `{` on the `for` I think - either that or your indentation is misleading as Sourav says.

Comment: @Clifford In all these years, I was trying to find someone who supports analogy of having the opening braces in the next line.Now I know I'm not alone. :)

Comment: @SouravGhosh I think the line-saver approach is commion in programming texts because you can get more code on the page where code split across pages is hard to follow.  In a text editor that is not an issue.  Steve McConnell in Code Compete 2nd. ed disagrees with me on the non-indentation of braces, but 30 years of experience tells me he's wrong.  All opinions on this point are however just that - opinion.  If you work in a team however, consistency is useful.